# What is the best way to handle Firestore with React?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, architecture, react-query

I'm mainly a react developer and I have very little knowledge about the back-end (just basics).  
I'm trying to implement a **react** project with Firebase using **Firestore** as a database, I usually go for **redux** or **react-query** to store data along with **axios** to handle requests. 
After some engineering I came up with the solution below :

```
// Function to get the Data using Firebase SDK
export const getMyData = async () => {
  return await getDocs(collection(db, `path/to/data`))
    .then(res => {
      const result = [];
      res.forEach(doc => result.push(doc.data()));
      return result;
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
};

// Custom React Hook that fetches the data , set the loading state and dispatch the results to the redux store 
export const useGetData = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const data = useAppSelector(state => state.data);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [refetch, setRefetch] = React.useState(false);

  const fetchdata = () => {
    setRefetch(true);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const getdata = async () => {
      if (!data || refetch) {
        setRefetch(false);
        setLoading(true);
        const data = await getMyData();
        dispatch(setdata(data));
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    getdata();
  }, [data, refetch, dispatch]);
  return { data, loading, fetchdata };
};
```

Basically the idea here is to use `useGetData` to manually fetch and manage loaders.
But To be honest i'm not very sure about this and I'd like to hear your opinions / recommendations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Repeatedly calling `getDocuments()` (or `get` in v8 and earlier of the SDK) is an antipattern on Firestore. If you want to show documents from Firestore and monitor for updates, use `onSnapshot` as shown in the documentation on [listening for updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

A common pattern for this is:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = () => {
    onSnapshot(collection(db, `path/to/data`), res => {
      const data = res.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
      dispatch(setdata(data));
    })
  };
  return () => unsubscribe();
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a pro tip, would you explain further what you meant by antipattern ?

Comment: Unlike most other cloud-hosted databases, Firestore (and Firebase's other database: Realtime Database) have built-in support for listening for updates to a data set. This makes poll-to-refresh (as your code does) unnecessary and less efficient. For a quick intro of this, see: https://youtu.be/xAsvwy1-oxE?t=374

Comment: It makes sense, so if I understood right, it will ask the database if anything has changed before retrieving data and avoid unnecessary fetches ?